# how to truncate values while calculating in a window function

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I hope my title somewhat reflects the issue...

I have table Courses which I track each year how many points a student got. Now I have to run a query which tallies the points. But: any row that passes 150 or a multiple of 150, on that year the student loses any points higher then TotaPoints/150.

Here is the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e84bf/10

Here is the simple schema, I put in the CorrectResult manually here for testing:

```
CREATE TABLE Courses
    ([Year] int, [Points] int, [CorrectResult] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Courses
    ([Year], [Points], [CorrectResult])
VALUES
    (1, 148, 148),
    (2, 4, 150),
    (3, 149, 299)
;
```

Here is my meanwhile incorrect query:

```
SELECT 
  Year,
  Points,
  CorrectResult,
  TotalCredits - LostPointsTally as RelevantPoints 
FROM (
  SELECT 
    Year,
    Points,
    CorrectResult,
    TotalCredits,
    LAG(LevelGroup, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Year) AS PreviousLevelGroup,
    CASE 
      WHEN LevelGroup > LAG(LevelGroup, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Year) THEN 
        TotalCredits - (LAG(LevelGroup, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Year) * 150)
      ELSE 
        0
    END AS LostPointsTally
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      Year,
      Points,
      CorrectResult,
      TotalCredits,
      FLOOR(TotalCredits / 150) + 1 AS LevelGroup
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        Year,
        Points,
        CorrectResult,
        SUM(CASE 
          WHEN Points > 150 THEN 150
          ELSE Points
        END) OVER (ORDER BY Year) AS TotalCredits
      FROM Courses
    ) t
  ) t1
) t2;
```

Running this query, on row 3 you get 300, which is wrong. we need to get 150+149 which is 299.

(I hope I come through clear, if not I'll be more than glad to clarify further)

Please advise

Thanks so much

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I think you;re over complicating it but more than 3 rows of data is needed to clearly see what is required.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, may I ask what I did not provide in my text? I put the precise schema, with the data, and the query I was trying. I'd be happy to know for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem, you want to calculate an *adjusted* running total where anytime a multiple of 150 is passed, the total is clamped at that 150 multiple. The running total for later rows continues from that point until the next 150 multiple is reached. Further, the points per record is limited to 150, so it is not possible to cross more that one multiple of 150 in the same year.

Because the calculation for each row depends on the non-trivial adjustment calculation from the previous row, I do not think this can be done using a straightforward aggregation with running totals and the LAG() function. This will require an iterative calculation, possibly using a recursive CTE (common table expression).

The following uses multiple CTEs to build up to the results. The first CTE applies a limit to the points that each year can contribute. The second CTE is a recursive CTE that includes the first year as a base and recursively includes later years joined to the prior year results.

I reworked your *LevelGroup* logic by calculating a `LevelUpThreshold` value (next multiple of 150) that limits the running sum for that year. It is then a matter of calculating the prior-adjusted-sum + current-adjusted-points and compare with the calculated `LevelUpThreshold` to select the new adjusted sum. The `LEAST()` function works quite nicely for this.

The resulting query would be something like:

```
WITH CTE_Adjusted_Points AS (
    SELECT C.*, LEAST(Points, 150) AS AdjustedPoints
    FROM Courses C
),
CTE_Adjusted_Sum AS (
    SELECT
        P.*,
        P.AdjustedPoints AS RawSum,
        P.AdjustedPoints AS AdjustedSum
    FROM CTE_Adjusted_Points P
    WHERE P.Year = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        P.*,
        S.AdjustedSum + P.AdjustedPoints AS RawSum,
        LEAST(S.AdjustedSum + P.AdjustedPoints, L.LevelUpThreshold) AS AdjustedSum
    FROM CTE_Adjusted_Sum S
    JOIN CTE_Adjusted_Points P ON P.Year = S.year + 1
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT (S.AdjustedSum / 150 + 1) * 150 AS LevelUpThreshold
    ) L
)
SELECT S.Year, S.Points, S.AdjustedPoints, S.RawSum, S.AdjustedSum, S.CorrectResult
FROM CTE_Adjusted_Sum S
ORDER BY S.Year;
```

The above logic assumes:

1. All `Points` values are non-negative.
2. Year starts at 1 and increments without duplicates or gaps.

Results (with some extra test data):

| Year | Points | AdjustedPoints | RawSum | AdjustedSum | CorrectResult |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 148 | 148 | 148 | 148 | 148 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | 152 | 150 | 150 |
| 3 | 149 | 149 | 299 | 299 | 299 |
| 4 | 10 | 10 | 309 | 300 | 300 |
| 5 | 500 | 150 | 450 | 450 | 450 |
| 6 | 70 | 70 | 520 | 520 | 520 |
| 7 | 70 | 70 | 590 | 590 | 590 |
| 8 | 70 | 70 | 660 | 600 | 600 |
| 9 | 70 | 70 | 670 | 670 | 670 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CfKtG_r6) for a working example.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the detailed answer. I also thought CTE would be useful, but could not get my head around it. In any event, Yes, all points are positive. but no, the year could be multiples of same year (though we can techincally group it beforehand), and can definetly have gaps. so Year+1 would not work. any other ideas?

Comment: To resolve potential duplicate (or gaps in) years, you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to assign a unique number to each course in the first CTE. Something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C.Year, ...) AS RowNum`. You would then use RowNum in place of Year throughout the remainder of the query. Note that multiple courses in the same year could potentially lead to multiple level advancements in that year. If that is not desired, you may need to group and combine courses in the same year.

Comment: Hi. Great! Perfect! Thanks so much. Only problem is the performance. im running it on 90K records, it takes forever. meanwhile its taking over 6 minutes. any ideas how we can improve the eficiency? maybe reduce to one cte? or change the cross apply to something else? by the way the first cte the AdjustedPoints is not needed. its always identical to plain Points. Thanks so so much.

Comment: hi. any way to improve performance? such as removing the cross apply? on my current db its taking 90 minutes to run. thanks again! just regular ctes and window functions will probably be much more efficient

Comment: @YisroelM.Olewski - To help with performance, I would need to know more about your actual data. I assume that you aren't calculating a single series covering 90,000 years. Perhaps you are calculating results over 10,000s of accounts over a few years each. You need to provide more information about your source table schema (including indexes), sample data, your actual query, and a [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) copy of the resulting execution plan.